# C++ std::printf("%u", 5) adds a number after the expected output

Tags: c++, xcode, printf

The output of the following code is `51` instead of the expected `5`. I use Xcode 6.4 with the LLVM compiler on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.4.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::cout << std::printf("%u", 5) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If have tried to supply an `int`, `unsigned long` and `uint32_t`, and I have swapped the `%u` for a `%d` and `%lu`, but I always get the same result: A strange number being after the intended `printf` output. Swapping the `5` for another number results in another unexpected number being added to the output. This is in a fresh project with no other code added. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Use `printf` or `cout`, not both.

Comment: Thank you all for your very quick answers, it all makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) returns an int. In your case it is returning `1` which is the number of characters written (`5`).

`cout` is printing that `1`, after `printf` prints `5` because you're chaining them together.

To just get `5`, say:

```
std::printf("%u\n", 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

[printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) returns number of printed characters, so '5' is printed by printf itself, then '1' is printed as result of `cout << result_of_print`

what you probably want is

`std::cout << 5u << std::endl;`

**Also: avoid mixing C style output (printf) with C++ style (std::cout)**

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on `std::hex` and output styles, such feedback is always welcome when getting started with a new language.

Comment: yeah, but it was my mistake :D I've thought I saw '%x' in printf :)

Answer (score 0):

Your using both `std::cout` and `std::printf`.

Just one one of them, like this:

```
std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
```

**OR**

```
std::printf("%u", t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix `cout` and `printf` together... what is happening is that `printf` returns the number of characters printed (in your case one character, which is `5`). So the `printf` statement is executed, printing `5`, but then `cout` prints the return value of `printf`, adding an extra `1`.